# iOS NSAttributedString on UIButton

Tags: ios, uibutton, nsattributedstring

I'm using **iOS 6**, so attributed strings should be easy to use, right? Well... not so much.

What I want to do:

Using a custom subclass of `UIButton` (it doesn't do anything custom to `titleLabel`), I'd like to have a multi-line, attributed title that is:

1. All caps (I realize that's not part of the attributes) on the first line
2. **Bolded** on the first line
3. **Underlined** on the first line
4. "Normal" weight on the second line
5. Non-underlined on the second line
6. Centered on both lines

I've been able to get #'s 1 through 5 so far (at least, I thought I did, but current testing is yielding errors with multi-line text), but when I tried to do something (anything!) to get the text to be centered, my app keeps crashing. When I try to get all 6 items working (through various methods), I get the following crash/error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 
'NSAttributedString invalid for autoresizing, 
it must have a single spanning paragraph style
(or none) with a non-wrapping lineBreakMode.'
```

Based on what I've tried, it appears that I can have one of the following options, but not both:

1. A multi-line, centered label
2. An attributed label

I can live with one or the other if I **must**, but I can't believe that I can't have what seems to be a fairly straightforward concept.

Can someone please tell me what I've got wrong?

Here's the last iteration of the code I'm trying:

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *style = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
[style setAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
[style setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

UIFont *font1 = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Medium" size:20.0f];
UIFont *font2 = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light"  size:20.0f];
NSDictionary *dict1 = @{NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName:@(NSUnderlineStyleSingle),  
                        NSFontAttributeName:font1};
NSDictionary *dict2 = @{NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName:@(NSUnderlineStyleNone),    
                        NSFontAttributeName:font2};

NSMutableAttributedString *attString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] init];
[attString appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"LINE 1\n"    attributes:dict1]];
[attString appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"line 2"      attributes:dict2]];
[[self buttonToStyle] setAttributedTitle:attString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[[self buttonToStyle] titleLabel] setNumberOfLines:0];
[[[self buttonToStyle] titleLabel] setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
```

Comment: What about styling a UILabel and adding it to the button?

Comment: Isn't `titleLabel` supposed to BE a `UILabel`? I guess I could do that, but I still feel like that's a bigger hammer than SHOULD be necessary.

Comment: It's iOS, nothing makes sense... I kid.  I messed with NSMutableAttributedString a while back and it was nothing but headaches.  My advice would be to keep things as simple and easy as possible.

Comment: I don't disagree, but I still also maintain that my desires, as listed above, aren't exactly "cutting edge"! ;-) What I don't understand is why I can do it with a stock `UILabel`, but it apparently isn't functional on a `UIButton`. Odd. Off to see if your idea will work.

Comment: @JeffCompton So... your answer works PERFECTLY! I still don't like the solution, though. It feels "kludgy" and wrong. I'm not arguing its efficacy, just that it shouldn't be necessary. Thanks for the help! If you wrap your comment as an answer, I'll accept it (unless someone gives me a way to "natively" do what I want).

Answer (score 105, accepted):

It looks to me like you forgot in your code to use the "style" object that you set up.. you just instantiated it. You should modify your code to look like this:

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *style = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
[style setAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
[style setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

UIFont *font1 = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Medium" size:20.0f];
UIFont *font2 = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light"  size:20.0f];
NSDictionary *dict1 = @{NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName:@(NSUnderlineStyleSingle),
                        NSFontAttributeName:font1,
                        NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:style}; // Added line
NSDictionary *dict2 = @{NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName:@(NSUnderlineStyleNone),
                        NSFontAttributeName:font2,
                        NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:style}; // Added line

NSMutableAttributedString *attString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] init];
[attString appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"LINE 1\n"    attributes:dict1]];
[attString appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"line 2"      attributes:dict2]];
[self.resolveButton setAttributedTitle:attString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[self.resolveButton titleLabel] setNumberOfLines:0];
[[self.resolveButton titleLabel] setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
```

Note that I only added the lines that define the NSParagraphStyleAttributeName.. everything else is the same.. and this is what I get for the button:

[image]

And here it is in Swift 3.0

```
let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
style.alignment = .center
style.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping

guard
    let font1 = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Medium", size: 20),
    let font2 = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 20)  else { return }

let dict1:[String:Any] = [
    NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName:NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue,
    NSFontAttributeName:font1,
    NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:style
]

let dict2:[String:Any] = [
    NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName:NSUnderlineStyle.styleNone.rawValue,
    NSFontAttributeName:font2,
    NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:style
]

let attString = NSMutableAttributedString()
attString.append(NSAttributedString(string: "LINE 1", attributes: dict1))
attString.append(NSAttributedString(string: "line 2", attributes: dict2))

button.setAttributedTitle(attString, for: .normal)
button.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
button.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
```

Comment: When I use Attributed text, was anybody has solution ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24525224/programmatically-change-title-color-of-uibutton-whose-title-set-as-attributed-in, I got the answer here.

Comment: How to add color in it?

Comment: I Got that
`NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white`

Comment: If you don't use underline style, it is necessary to add a '\n' char between line 1 and 2 to force a line break.

Answer (score 17):

With Swift 5.1 and iOS 13.1, you can use the `UIButton` subclass implementation below in order to solve your problem:

```swift
import UIKit

class CustomButton: UIButton {

    required init(title: String, subtitle: String) {
        super.init(frame: CGRect.zero)

        let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        style.alignment = NSTextAlignment.center
        style.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping

        let titleAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key : Any] = [
            NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.label,
            NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle : NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue,
            NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFont.TextStyle.largeTitle),
            NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle : style
        ]
        let subtitleAttributes = [
            NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.label,
            NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFont.TextStyle.body),
            NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle : style
        ]

        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: title, attributes: titleAttributes)
        attributedString.append(NSAttributedString(string: "\n"))
        attributedString.append(NSAttributedString(string: subtitle, attributes: subtitleAttributes))

        setAttributedTitle(attributedString, for: UIControl.State.normal)
        titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
        titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

*Usage:*

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let button = CustomButton(title: "Title", subtitle: "Subtitle")
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(button)

        let horizontalConstraint = button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor)
        let verticalConstraint = button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([horizontalConstraint, verticalConstraint])
    }

}
```

---

As an alternative if you really need a button of type `system`, you may use the following code:

```swift
import UIKit

extension UIButton {

    static func customSystemButton(title: String, subtitle: String) -> UIButton {
        let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        style.alignment = NSTextAlignment.center
        style.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping

        let titleAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key : Any] = [
            NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle : NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue,
            NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFont.TextStyle.largeTitle),
            NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle : style
        ]
        let subtitleAttributes = [
            NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFont.TextStyle.body),
            NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle : style
        ]

        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: title, attributes: titleAttributes)
        attributedString.append(NSAttributedString(string: "\n"))
        attributedString.append(NSAttributedString(string: subtitle, attributes: subtitleAttributes))

        let button = UIButton(type: UIButton.ButtonType.system)
        button.setAttributedTitle(attributedString, for: UIControl.State.normal)
        button.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
        button.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping

        return button
    }

}
```

*Usage:*

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let button = UIButton.customSystemButton(title: "Title", subtitle: "Subtitle")
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(button)

        let horizontalConstraint = button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor)
        let verticalConstraint = button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([horizontalConstraint, verticalConstraint])
    }

}
```

---

The two screen shots below show the result display for the `UIButton` subclass (on the left) and for the `system` type button (on the right):

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Two line `UIButton` with `NSAttributedString` title in `Swift 5.1`:

```
func customizeSubscribeButton() {
    subscribeButton.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 2
    let title = NSMutableAttributedString()
    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.alignment = .center
    let part1 = NSAttributedString(string: "SUBSCRIBE FOR 12 MONTH\n",
                                   attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white,
                                                NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 24, weight: .semibold),
                                                NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle])
    let part2 = NSAttributedString(string: "999.00 RUB ECONOMY 85%",
                                   attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white,
                                                NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12, weight: .light),
                                                NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle])
    title.append(part1)
    title.append(part2)
    subscribeButton.setAttributedTitle(title, for: .normal)
}
```