# Programmatically change title color of UIButton whose title set as attributed in iOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios7, uibutton, nsattributedstring

I have added one `UIButton` in my `UITableView` programmatically. My problem is i need to give the `Letter Spacing` as well as need to change the button title color. I have given the `Letter Spacing` in button title text using below code, but title text color is not changing.

here is my code :

```
btnLogin = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
btnLogin.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 42);
btnLogin.titleLabel.font = customFont;

NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"LOG IN"];

[attributedString addAttribute:NSKernAttributeName
                         value:@(spacing)
                         range:NSMakeRange(0, [@"LOG IN" length])];

[btnLogin setAttributedTitle:attributedString forState:UIControlStateNormal];

btnLogin.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell_highlighted.png"]];

[btnLogin setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; //it's not working.

[btnLogin addTarget:self action:@selector(onClickLogin) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[cell addSubview:btnLogin];
[cell.contentView bringSubviewToFront:btnLogin];
```

Can you please help me how to change the button title color here? Thanks.

Comment: Add this line: `[attributedString addAttribute:NSForegroundAttributeName value:[UIColor whiteColor] range:NSMakeRange(0, [@"LOG IN" length])];`

Comment: wohh great.. its working. Only need to change NSForegroundAttributeName with NSForegroundColorAttributeName. Thanks alot@Larme

Comment: My bad, forgot "Color" in the name attribute. Well, the reason is because `attributedTitle` is a "new" property, and `titleColor` works for `title` property of `UIButton`, not for the `attributedTitle`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I got answer with help of @Larme.

Only need to add this line :

```
[attributedString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor whiteColor] range:NSMakeRange(0, [@"LOG IN" length])];
```

Thanks to all!!

Comment: Instead of getting the length from the string, you can use attributedString.length, like: NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length)

Answer (score 2):

**Swift Version**

```
 attributedString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.skyBlue, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.string.length))
```