# Multiline NSAttributed String as UIButton Title

Tags: ios, string, swift, uibutton, nsattributedstring

My question is similar in theory to this one: [iOS NSAttributedString on UIButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17756067/ios-nsattributedstring-on-uibutton)

I am looking to make the title of my button read as:

"An underlined string

Some text"

This needs to be done in swift and 100% programmatically.

I am attempting to do this by creating the underlined section using an NSMutableAttributedString and then appending that to the other text (which leads with a newline character). However, that gives me the error "Cannot assign value of type 'Void' ('aka'()') to type 'NSMutableAttributedString"

Code below:

```
var patientName = NSMutableAttributedString(string:"Patient Name", attributes: underlineAttributes)
var clickforinfomessage = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "\nclick for patient info")
clickforinfomessage = clickforinfomessage.appendAttributedString(patientName)
startVisitButton.setAttributedTitle(clickforinfomessage, forState: .Normal)
```

Comment: `clickforinfomessage = clickforinfomessage.appendAttributedString(patientName)` to `clickforinfomessage.appendAttributedString(patientName)`. There is no return in this method (`appendAttributedString()`) as says the error.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
let dict1 = [NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: NSUnderlineStyle.StyleSingle.rawValue]

let attString = NSMutableAttributedString()
attString.appendAttributedString(NSAttributedString(string: "Patient Name\n", attributes: dict1))
attString.appendAttributedString(NSAttributedString(string: "click for patient info", attributes: nil))
startVisitButton.setAttributedTitle(attString, forState: .Normal)
startVisitButton.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
startVisitButton.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
```

And result will be:

[image]

Comment: How to change the title size here ?

Comment: You can add font size attribute. @AbhishekMitra

Comment: In iOS 11 setting numberOfLines = 0 fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the number of line for the button's title label

```
let attrTet = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Test is \ne next line.", attributes: nil)
testButton.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
testButton.setTitle(attrTet.string, forState: .Normal)
```

Code View:

[image: Code View]

Output:

[image: Output]

Comment: Doesn't work. The documentation clearly mentions that the attributedTitle is assumed to be single line.

Comment: Maybe you are not trying it properly this works 100%, make sure that your button doest have a fixed height.